# error of inserting a fixed value into a table with other columns in SQL server 2008R?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows-7

I need to insert some data into a table in SQL server 2008R on win7.

I need to find 10 smallest value from a table and insert them into another table.

My query:

```
 DECLARE @fixed_value INT 

 SET @@fixed_value = 966

 INSERT INTO table2
 SELECT @fixed_value AS new_id , TOP 10 a.id, a.value 
 FROM table1 as a 
 ORDER BY a.value ASC
```

table1:

```
  id (int) value (float)
  758      348974.3689
  7985     6976.0584
```

table2 expected results:

```
 new_id (int)  id (int) value (float)
 966           758      348974.3689
 966           7985     6976.0584
```

I got error:

```
 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TOP'.
```

How to insert @fixed_value into a table with other columns as new id ?

thanks!

Comment: SELECT TOP @fixed_value AS new_id , a.id, a.value is the correct syntax.

Comment: BTW you have 2 `@` in `@@fixed_value = 966`

Answer (score 2):

`TOP` needs to go right after the `SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO table2(new_id, id, value)
    SELECT TOP 10 @fixed_value AS new_id , a.id, a.value 
    FROM table1 as a 
    ORDER BY a.value ASC;
```

Also, you should use column lists when doing inserts.

Comment: Is the column name of the table you are inserting into not 'new_id'?

Comment: The column list in the brackets lacks one item. Or the second underscore there should be a comma.